$H^{s,\infty}$ via Triebel Lizorkin spaces
I know that
$F^s_{p,2} = H^{s,p}$
for $p \in (1, \infty)$, but what about $H^{s,1}$ and $H^{s,\infty}$? I know one extension for $F^0_{\infty,2}$ which should be BMO. But how do I get the $H^{s,\infty}$ through Triebel?

These are not standard notations. But for the letter one you can search $bmo^s$, which is $F_{\infty2}^s$.
